# Using faceted search for items which have ajax calls

Tags: javascript, php, facet, faceted-search, nouislider

First thank you for all help that has so far allowed me not to need to ask a question at all!

I'm stuck on this particular part of my project; I have a functioning page that calls products from the relevant SQL table, uses an ajax call to fill in appropriate data, and forms a nouislider with this data (see http://refreshless.com/nouislider/). However when I try to make these items searchable by faceted search (as per http://eikes.github.io/facetedsearch/) I no longer get my nouislider displayed at all (or the ajax data).

This is a shortened version of the functioning code before being faceted:

```
   <?php
require_once 'sqllogin.php';  

$connectionfortrending = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password,         $db_database);

if ($connectionfortrending->connect_error) die($connectionfortrending->connect_error);

$querycalltrendingproducts = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE trending='1' LIMIT 1";
     $resultcalltrendingproducts = $connectionfortrending-    >query($querycalltrendingproducts);

if (!$resultcalltrendingproducts) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());


      $alltrending = array();
while($rowstrending = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultcalltrendingproducts)) 
 {
  $alltrending = array();
  $alltrending[] = $rowstrending;





?>

            <td>

<a href="<?php
    echo $alltrending[0]['productkey'];
        ?>.php"><img id="trending1" border="0" style="width:200px;height:250px" src=<?php
    echo $alltrending[0]['productimg'];
    ?>></a>
                <div class="infotext">
    <?php
  echo $alltrending[0]['productinfo'];         
    ?>
        </div>


      <?php
}

    ?>


        <div class="priceshower" style="display:inline;">&#163<span class="priceshower" style="display:inline;" id="pledgepriceviewtrend1" align="center"></span></div>

        <div style="margin-left:80px;" class="slider" id="trendingslider1"></div>




<script>
trendingslider1.noUiSlider({
start: [ tslider1v3 ],

range: {
    'min': [  tslider1v1 ],
    'max': [ tslider1v3 ]
},
        serialization: {
    lower: [

        $.Link({
            target: $("#pledgepriceviewtrend1")      
        }),

                    $.Link({
            target: $("#pledgepricesubmittrend1")      
        })

    ],

            format: {

        decimals: 2,

    }
}

});





function getGroupTrendingSlider1(){      

valuestr = $("#trendingslider1").val();   
valuenum = Number(valuestr);

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
  document.getElementById("pplleftingroup").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","posttrending1v3.php?q=",true);
</script>
```

I have tried placing the whole lot (the SQL call and the HTML div elements) into the var item_template part of the faceted search code, as below, but this does not show the slider. For example, this is just the slider javascript having been placed in the faceted search code:

```
 var item_template =  
                   'var trendingslider1 = $(\'#trendingslider1\'); ' +
                           'trendingslider1.noUiSlider({' +
    'start: [ tslider1v3 ],' +

   'range: {' +
    '\'min\': [  tslider1v1 ],' +
    '\'max\': [ tslider1v3 ]' +
    '},' +
        'serialization: {' +
    'lower: [' +

        '$.Link({' +
            'target: $("#pledgepriceviewtrend1")' +      
        '}),' +

                   ' $.Link({' +
            'target: $("#pledgepricesubmittrend1")      ' +
        '})' +

        '],' +

           ' format: {' +

        'decimals: 2,' +

    '}' +
    '}' +

'});' +





'function getGroupTrendingSlider1(){   ' +   

'valuestr = $("#trendingslider1").val();  ' + 
'valuenum = Number(valuestr);' +

  'if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {' +

'xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();' +
  '} else { // code for IE6, IE5' +
  '  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");' +
  '}' +
  'xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {' +
    'if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {' +
  'document.getElementById("pplleftingroup").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;' +
   '}' +
  '}' +
'xmlhttp.open("GET","posttrending1v3.php?q=",true);'
     ;
```

Am I going about this in the wrong way?  Is it something to do with trying to use both the nouislider.js and facetedsearch.js files together?? Any help much appreciated!
Chris

Comment: what JS error are you receiving in the console?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, just no display of the nouislider itself.  All the rest of the elements I faceted work fine, just the slider that doesn't show at all. You'll notice above that the slider receives values for 'min' and 'max' but this doesn't appear to be the problem because if I replace these with figures the slider still does not show. Hence me wondering if it may be to do with having javascript within the var = item_template javascript?